# After changing display template of search results - search isn't working

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search-results, display-template

I'm changing a display template (copy `Item_Person`, modify, and add `Item_Person_WorkPhone`) and adding a new search type.

It works, but only with my administrator account. Users with `Read` permission can't see results. They receive the error:

> Something went wrong...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you have **published** the HTML-file of your new display template, so that the HTML-file and the generated JavaScript-file can be accessed by all users.

The files of your display template should be located at:

```
<siteurl>/_catalogs/masterpage/Display%20Templates/Content%20Web%20Parts
```